# HTML CSS center buttons

Tags: html, css

I'm having some troubles centering buttons on my page.

HTML-Code

```css
.banner {
  background-color: #101723;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 16px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
  color: #FFFFFF; 
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```

```html
<section class="banner">
  <a href="" target="_blank"><div class="button">BUTTON 1</div></a> 
  <a href="" target="_blank"><div class="button">BUTTON 2</div></a>
  <a href="" target="_blank"><div class="button">BUTTON 3</div></a>
</section>
```

The 3 buttons should be centered in a container. I tried everything but it seems I miss out something.

Comment: Have you tried declaring `text-align: center` on `.banner`? A guide for centering things: https://jsfiddle.net/o4dzsc0k/1/ **&** https://jsfiddle.net/o4dzsc0k/2/

Comment: @DavidHope For clarity, that will only work on *block elements* and is deprecated - just a heads up. It will still work though. **Ref:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/align

Comment: U just need to add text-align:center css to your .banner class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add `text-align: center` to your `.banner` class:

```css
.banner {
    background-color: #101723;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 50px 0;
    text-align:center;
}

.button {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 16px 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    vertical-align: middle;

    border: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
    color: #FFFFFF; 
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```

```html
<section class="banner">
  <a href="" target="_blank"><div class="button">BUTTON 1</div></a> 
  <a href="" target="_blank"><div class="button">BUTTON 2</div></a>
  <a href="" target="_blank"><div class="button">BUTTON 3</div></a>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Centering in CSS has always been something hard to implement. I discover the flexbox method which I think is the best.

```
.container {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     align-items: center; /* To center vertically */
     justify-content: center; /* To center horizontally */
}
.item {
}
```

You can find all you need here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp