# centering vertically and horizontally several buttons css

Tags: html, css

I wanted to center both vertically and horizontally my buttons so I got inspired by this [tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/). However, I think, because of `position: fixed;` my three buttons are on top of each other, and I would like them to be next to each other (but still centered horizontally). I sort of guess why this wouldn't work (because I place them all at the same place) but don't really know how to fix this. Adding `display: inline;` didn't help.

I also saw this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46954736/html-css-center-buttons) post so I tried a second .css but this still didn't work (this time the buttons were on the top left, but not on top of each other).

My HTML code is the following:

```
<body>
    <button name="button1" class="buttonsWelcome" type="submit" value="HaploSFHI">1</button>
    <button name="button2" class="buttonsWelcome" type="submit" value="tool2">2</button>
    <button name="button3" class="buttonsWelcome" type="submit" value="tool3">3</button>
</body>
```

and my first css:

```
.buttonsWelcome {
    width: 200px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    display: inline;
    position: fixed;
}
```

and my second css:

```
.buttonsWelcome {
    width: 200px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:center;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this!

```css
.container{   
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.buttonsWelcome {
    width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <button name="button1" class="buttonsWelcome" type="submit" value="HaploSFHI">1</button>
    <button name="button2" class="buttonsWelcome" type="submit" value="tool2">2</button>
    <button name="button3" class="buttonsWelcome" type="submit" value="tool3">3</button>
</div>
```

If you want you can also change the `.container` to `body` in CSS and remove the above `div` in HTML code but it is good to use a separate block to add them otherwise all of your code will be centered when you use it with your `body` tag.

Moreover, there are a lot of ways to do this and this is only a one method of them. Look at this [W3School CSS Layout](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp) page if you want to know more about how to align items to center

Thanks and best regards!

Answer (score 1):

Try with flexbox:

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.buttonsWelcome {
    width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.buttonsWelcome {
    width: 50px;
    display: inline;
}

.button{
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    text-align:center;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
    <button name="button1" class="buttonsWelcome" type="submit" value="HaploSFHI">1</button>
    <button name="button2" class="buttonsWelcome" type="submit" value="tool2">2</button>
    <button name="button3" class="buttonsWelcome" type="submit" value="tool3">3</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using Flexbox with minor updates to your HTML mark-up. Use 100vh to achieve full height of the page across devices.

```css
.container {   
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button name="button1" type="submit" value="HaploSFHI">1</button>
  <button name="button2" type="submit" value="tool2">2</button>
  <button name="button3" type="submit" value="tool3">3</button>
 </div>
```